# Video Recording using GLSurfaceview in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to record video by using GLSurfaceview in android. But every time when i tap to record, it gives me null pointer exception onPause.

here is my code to record video

```
mCamera = new CameraLoader();
    buttonn_capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try{

                        if (recording) {

                            mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording

                            recording = false;
                        } else {

                            // Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                            mCamera.releaseCamera();

                            if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {

                                finish();
                            }

                            try {
                                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                            recording = true;
                            // myButton.setText("Cancel");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please tap and hold to record!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        reload();
                    }
                }
            });

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        mCamera.mCameraInstance.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera.mCameraInstance);
        // Step 2: Set sources

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);


        mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                "MusicDubs");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();

        }

        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault())
                .format(new Date());

        CameraInfo caminfo = new CameraInfo();
        mCamera.mCameraInstance.getCameraInfo(0, caminfo);
        if (caminfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {

            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0,
                    CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            mediaRecorder
                    .setOrientationHint(270);

        } else if (caminfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0,
                    CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            mediaRecorder
                    .setOrientationHint(270);
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

        }
        //mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(20);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(120);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/"
                + "_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(glSurfaceView.getHolder()
                .getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
           // releaseMediaPlayer();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
           // releaseMediaPlayer();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.mCameraInstance.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }
```

on Activity pause and resume i added that code

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCamera.onResume();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mCamera.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

here is my camera class to load camera

```
private class CameraLoader {

    private int mCurrentCameraId = 0;
    private Camera mCameraInstance;

    public void onResume() {
        setUpCamera(mCurrentCameraId);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        releaseCamera();
    }

    public void switchCamera() {
        releaseCamera();
        mCurrentCameraId = (mCurrentCameraId + 1) % mCameraHelper.getNumberOfCameras();
        setUpCamera(mCurrentCameraId);
    }

    private void setUpCamera(final int id) {
        mCameraInstance = getCameraInstance(id);
        Parameters parameters = mCameraInstance.getParameters();
        // TODO adjust by getting supportedPreviewSizes and then choosing
        // the best one for screen size (best fill screen)
        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
                Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        }
        mCameraInstance.setParameters(parameters);

        int orientation = mCameraHelper.getCameraDisplayOrientation(
                ActivityCamera.this, mCurrentCameraId);
        CameraInfo2 cameraInfo = new CameraInfo2();
        mCameraHelper.getCameraInfo(mCurrentCameraId, cameraInfo);
        boolean flipHorizontal = cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        mGPUImage.setUpCamera(mCameraInstance, orientation, flipHorizontal, false);
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    private Camera getCameraInstance(final int id) {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = mCameraHelper.openCamera(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        mCameraInstance.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCameraInstance.release();
        mCameraInstance = null;
    }
}
```

Its behavior is very strange, I didn't get why it is giving me null pointer exception onPause because there is no point of getting camera null there. please tell me where i'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: is there anybody who can help??

Comment: Which `onPause()`, the one in your Activity or the one in CameraLoader? Which exact line is failing? When do you initialize mCamera?

Comment: mCamera is initialized. OnPause of activity fails and onPause() of class fails too because it is calling to that method.